# Batch Rename not renaming objects

Tags: objects

I have a set of objects inside a collection generated from the Dupli Curve addon. I need to rename them all with a certain prefix. There are hundreds of objects across several collections.

Here is my setup. I have only selected the objects inside of one collection.
[image: image 1]
Why does the Batch Rename window say "Rename 0 Object(s)"? When I click OK, no objects get renamed.

I tried this with objects in a collection that Dupli Curve did not create, and it works fine, but I don't know of anything that Dupli Curve is doing that would stop the objects from being able to be renamed. Renaming them one by one works, but there's hundreds of them and that would take forever.

Comment: Are the objects unselectable in the viewport by any chance ?

Comment: I agree with Gorgious. Your objects are not selected. Their names are all grey in the outliner. If you select an object its name will be highlighted in orange. Multiple selected objects are highlighted in red. (The orange object is the so-called active object). But your selection is still grey. If objects are [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7QHs.png](disabled for selection) then only their background color changes. Long story short, check the toggles in the filter.

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks! That was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My objects were not marked as selectable. I did not notice that because I had the "selectable" toggle hidden.

[image: imgdesc]

Answer (score 0):

Any reason my Collections are not being renamed?

[image]